# Pometheus-operator - modify Grafana mixin dashboard

Tags: prometheus, grafana

Whenever I try to edit the provisioned dashboards I get an error stating that the provisioned dashboard can't be edited. I saw that there is an option to allow changes from the UI, but my questions is if there is a way to modify it in an automatic/code way. I want to be able to add additions to the mixin without interacting with that repo but a clone of mine.

Answer (score 1):

You should use https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/prometheus-operator helm chart , also you can write Grafana dashboard script that would create dashboard dynamically , can be update as well later on.